# Ran out of flooring

Tags: flooring, vinyl

I just finished installing vinyl planks in a spare room with leftover flooring. I’m about 2” short on one wall. This vinyl plank is discontinued. Any idea on how to fill in this gap? Thank you!

Comment: I know this won't help you now, but you always want to buy at least 10 percent more flooring than you will actually need, in case a piece is ruined and needs replacing. Having said that i would contact the company where you bought the stuff and see if someone will track down a piece nationwide, at other stores. Check OfferUp, craigslist etc.   Nationwide. The manufacturer may still have small amounts....I'd call them too. Good luck! Otherwise hide it with furniture. Or, redo the entire thing using new product that you buy at sufficient quantities...

Comment: Appreciate it. It was leftover from another project and I miscalculated. I was thinking of buying something very similar but of course I only need one plank. Or maybe even a transition piece. Or just paint the floor.

Comment: You're welcome! I would call all the places suggested and then some. Salvage businesses might also have pieces.

Comment: Put the gap under a cupboard or other piece of furniture. But in future, make sure you have enough before starting to lay it.

Answer (score 3):

Tricks for dealing with being 2" short on flooring:

1. Steal pieces that will be in a closet or under furniture along the wall, and move them to the visible part. Replace the moved piece with new flooring that looks close, and will be hidden in the closet or under a hutch or buffet cabinet etc.. If you don't have a hutch, buy one, new or used. If in a closet, you can use a patch of carpet.
2. Thicken the baseboard by replacing it with a thicker piece (going from 1/2in to 3/4in thick) and/or adding quarter round moulding or inside corner moulding.
3. Buy more flooring that fits (same click-in / T&G, and same thickness) but is of a different colour, and make the difference a feature by mixing old & new tiles/planks in a pattern. If the click seam or T&G doesn't quite fit, use glue on the seam. If it's a floating floor (likely), do not glue to the sub-floor.
4. Add a decorative trim/band all around the perimeter of the floor using different flooring. If a floating floor, apply a firm floating underlayment to glue the trim and the main flooring to it at their seam.
5. Make a trim or band from a transition strip or "reducer" which gets glued over the flooring and tucked under the baseboard.
6. Move the walls

Comment: That’s hilarious! I actually found two strips that I cut off earlier that is 2”! So it all worked out. Thank you!

Comment: That's great @Mary, thanks for the update. I hope the above is valuable to other future readers. Keep your questions coming, Welcome to Home Improvement DIY, and make sure to take the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)